# Production testing without impacting marketing conversion goals?

Tags: asp.net, testing, analytics

Are there any solutions for testing form submissions without impacting marketing conversion? Anytime we push a new version live and do all of our cross browser testing we end up logging a bunch of conversions which artificially inflate conversion.

The work-around we use right now, is a user control (asp.net) that is set visible=false if a web.config key is set to false, and true if set to true. Our concern to this is if someone changes the JS inside this conversion control in such a way that it breaks the site we would never know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to set a flag in your test sessions by hitting a landing page:

www.yoursite.com/?testing=true

Your landing page would set a session cookie (or some other session persistence). Then you setup your analytics controls so they don't render if that value is present.